# System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: validation, hyperlink, telerik, buttonclick, radeditor

I have a telerik radscheduler. I make appointments on it. To add an appointment I have date boxes and a radeditor. On the radeditor I have entered text like this "my test link". I made the word link as a hyperlink (pointing to some link on the internet). I have a submit buttton that adds the appointment. WOrks fine. I click to edit the appointment.Edit it and now save it and it gives me this exception "System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ".  I put validaterequest="false" and it works,but I am reading it is not safe/correct way. How do i proceed?If you need info,please ask.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you pass HTML to a field you later edit with a simple textbox, so such an error is expected. Perhaps where you use a RadEditor to get HTML, you should not.